# Tiles + Spring + wildfly 11 + java 8: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"

Tags: spring, wildfly, tiles

I deploy a ear with spring4, tiles 3.0.7, java 8 and in wildfly 11 but i get the following error:

> :45:18,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
>       00:45:18,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
>       00:45:18,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final)
>   started in 15761ms - Started 915 of 1144 services (356 services are
>   lazy, passive or on-demand)
>       00:45:19,773 ERROR Digester:789 - Digester.getParser: 
>       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
>         at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(SAXParserFactory.java:394)
>         at __redirected.__SAXParserFactory.setSchema(__SAXParserFactory.java:158)
>         at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:536)
>         at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:786)
>         at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
>         at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:325)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResource(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:150)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:234)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:203)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:192)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:68)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:174)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:131)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:105)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:49)
>         at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:89)
>         at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:286)
>         at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:273)
>         at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.isRenderable(DefinitionRenderer.java:64)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:116)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:483)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
>         at

I tried a lot of solutions but they dont works. 
I use tiles version 3.0.7

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue as you while trying to upgrade from tiles 1 to 3.
Anyway my fix was to upgrade the xercesimpl version to 2.11.0

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```